# save range Slider value in state and initiate the axios request while button click

Tags: reactjs, axios, bind, rangeslider

I am trying to save the Range-slider value .If i click "NEXT" i want it save the value in 'Squarefeet' variable and redirect to another page .I have built a Rest API in the backend to bind and save the value in database.The code is something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-rangeslider'
import Link from "next/link";
import axios from "axios";
import getConfig from "next/config";
const config = getConfig();

class Horizontal extends Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {
            apiUrl:config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
        }
    }
    handleChangeStart = () => {
        console.log('Change event started')
    };
    handleChange = value => {
        this.setState({
            value: value
        })};

    handleChangeComplete = () => {
        console.log('Change event completed')
    };
    saveValue = () => {
        console.log('saveValue ...', this.state);

        axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {
            'squareFeet':this.state.value,

        },  {}  )
    };

    render () {
        const { value } = this.state
        return (
            <div>

                <div className='slider'  style={{ marginTop:'165px',marginLeft:'319px',width:'700px',backgroundColor:'EF5350'}} >

                    <Slider min={850} max={5000} value={value} onChangeStart={this.handleChangeStart}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
                    />
                    <div className='value'>{value} Squarefeet</div>
                    <div style={{marginTop:'86px'}}>
                        <Link prefetch href="/estimate"><a href="#" >


                            <span onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={() => this.saveValue()} >Next</span></a></Link>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Horizontal
```

I am not getting how to make it work to bind and save.How should i do it?

Comment: And what is exactly the problem you are experiencing? The code seems right. You have the value in the `state` and you are sending it to the server.

Comment: I am not getting the value in  the backend. My database works fine for all other attributes

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but in your description you say you expect a `Squarefeet` parameter, but you are sending `squareFeet`.

Comment: what do you mean by you're not getting the value in the backend? At first look, you're accessing `value` from `this.state` inside render, but it's not defined in the constructor. You should have a look at that.